# What is best way of solving this query on involving 2 Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I currently looking for the best way to resolve a query I have about 2 Pandas dataframes. The two dataframes are as follows:

1. The first one (`gradebook_df`) is the main grade book which contains student's ID number along with their scores for all assignments.
2. The second one (`assignment_2_df`) is the df that contains students grade for assignment 2 and their student ID number.

gradebook_df

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| student ID  | assignment_1_score | assignment_2_score | final_exam_score |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234        |  23                | Nan                | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000        |  97                | Nan                | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0234        |  56                | Nan                | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

assignment_2_df:

```
------------------------------------
| student ID  | assignment_2_score | 
------------------------------------
| 1234        |  90                | 
------------------------------------
| 0000        |  87                | 
------------------------------------
| 0234        |  100               | 
------------------------------------
```

My Goal is to populate the `assignment_2_score` from `assignment_2_df` into `gradebook_df` for each student.

**So the finally `gradebook_df` will look like the following:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| student ID  | assignment_1_score | assignment_2_score | final_exam_score |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234        |  23                | 90                 | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000        |  97                | 97                 | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0234        |  56                | 100                | Nan              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone provide the most efficient way of achieving this?

Currently, I am implementing this in the following manner:

```py
gradebook_df["assignment_2_score"] = gradebook_df["student ID"].apply(lambda x : getScore(x))

def getScore(studentID):
    score_as_list = list(assignment_2_df[assignment_2_df["student ID"] == studentID]["assignment_2_score"])
    score = score_as_list[0]
    return score
```

This gives the correct answer but I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way of achieving this task. Any help will be appreciated. I have tried searching the internet but couldn't get the words to frame the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


gradebook_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "student ID": ["1234", "0000", "0234"],
    "assignment_1_score": [23, 97, 56],
    "assignment_2_score": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "final_exam_score": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
})

assignment_2_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "student ID": ["1234", "0000", "0234"],
    "assignment_2_score": [90, 87, 100]
})
```

---

```py
result = (
    gradebook_df.set_index("student ID")
    .combine_first(
        assignment_2_df.set_index("student ID")
    )
)
print(result)

student ID  assignment_1_score  assignment_2_score  final_exam_score
1234        23                  90.0                nan 
0000        97                  87.0                nan 
0234        56                  100.0               nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 gradebook_df["assignment_2_score"] = assignment_2_df["assignment_2_score"]
```